# Print a calendar starting from today's date

Tags: python, python-3.x, calendar

I want to print a calendar of the current month but starting from today's date in python. Is there any way I can do this?
Only thing I thought to try was :

```
import calendar
y = int(input("Input the year : "))
m = int(input("Input the month : "))
d = int (input("Input the day: "))
print(calendar.month(y, m, d))
```

which in retrospect is a dumb idea because all it did was :

[image: print result]

but considering my 3 day experience in python it seemed dumb enough to work.

I want the end result to look something like this:

[image: wanted result]

Essentially,I want the calendar to show only the remaining days of the month,instead of the whole month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calender method returns a string. You can use conventual string manipulation methods to modify the string before printing - f.e. regex replacement:

```
import calendar
import re

y = 2020
m = 5 
d = 15
h = calendar.month(y, m, 3) # 3 is the width of the date column, not the day-date
print(h)
print()

# replace all numbers before your day, take care of either spaces or following \n

for day in range(d):
    # replace numbers at the start of a line
    pattern = rf"\n{day} "
    h = re.sub(pattern, "\n  " if day < 10 else "\n   ", h)
    # replace numbers in the middle of a line
    pattern = rf" {day} "
    h = re.sub(pattern, "   " if day < 10 else "    ", h)
    # replace numbers at the end of a line
    pattern = rf" {day}\n"
    h = re.sub(pattern, "  \n" if day < 10 else "   \n", h)

print(h)
```

Output:

```
          May 2020
Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
                  1   2   3
  4   5   6   7   8   9  10
 11  12  13  14  15  16  17
 18  19  20  21  22  23  24
 25  26  27  28  29  30  31


# after replacement    

          May 2020
Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
                           
                           
                 15  16  17
 18  19  20  21  22  23  24
 25  26  27  28  29  30  31
```